# What's the solution and the right way to convert digits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, numbers, number-formatting

following all qa about converting digits in javascript in Stackoverflow. However, I had a problem/ question

**method one**

```javascript
        // Convert Persian and Arabic digits to English using the new function
        var convertedValue = convertDigitsToEnglish(currentPhoneValue);

    // Function to convert Persian and Arabic digits to English digits
    function convertDigitsToEnglish(value) {
        var persianDigits = '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹';
        var arabicDigits = '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩';
        var englishDigits = '0123456789';

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            value = value.replace(new RegExp(persianDigits[i], 'g'), englishDigits[i]);
            value = value.replace(new RegExp(arabicDigits[i], 'g'), englishDigits[i]);
        }

        return value;
    }
```

[image]

**method two**

```javascirpt
        // Convert Persian and Arabic digits to English
        var convertedValue = convert_number.toNormal(phoneField.val());

var convert_number = (function () {
    var numerals = {
        persian: ["۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹"],
        arabic: ["٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"]
    };

    return {
        toNormal: function (str) {
            if (!str) {
                return '';
            }
            var num, i, len = str.length, result = "";

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                num = numerals["persian"].indexOf(str[i]);
                num = num != -1 ? num : numerals["arabic"].indexOf(str[i]);
                if (num == -1) num = str[i];
                result += num;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

in the method one works only for Persian/Farsi digits! and why doesn't it work correctly at all for the Arabic language?
arabic digits numbers `٤٥٦‍` (four five and six) numbers are not converted to English/Latin numbers. we defined this in the code and it shouldn't be a problem and it should work correctly, but it doesn't and these three numbers can't be converted, and doesn't accept these numbers!

in method two. both Persian and Arabic languages converted and no problem with this method.

For better explanations for my question so that nothing is missed. Let's say this is for a mobile number field.
I have also specified elsewhere that a keyboard the person cannot enter any additional characters such as asterisk, plus, minus, etc., other than the numbers 0 to 9.

```javascript
        // Remove non-numeric characters
        var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

In order for the Arabic and Persian numbers not to be recognized as foreign, I converted them to English numbers with this (upper convert function). So that the user can enter numbers with English, Farsi, and Arabic numbers. And it doesn't matter what language it is in. Converts to English in any digit. Also, prevents the entry of additional characters.

**I also used the pattern solution instead of these (convert), but it is ignored by the browser in different situations, and it is also suitable for English only. And it is not suitable for Persian and Arabic.
Was my method correct? Is there a better, shorter and cleaner way? Why the first method does not work correctly for some Arabic numbers? But does the second method work correctly?**

Comment: Can you show an example usage of `convertDigitsToEnglish` that doesn't work?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: In an HTML page, both methods may work well. but When I use these methods on the checkout page of WordPress. Because of the heaps of other code on that page. Interference may cause problems for the first method However, there does not seem to be any interference., which does not have a convincing reason. because it works But only the numbers 4, 5, and 6 are not converted! And I did not understand the reason! If the code won't work, it shouldn't work at all. But why does the code work, but these three numbers are not converted? And the second method seems to have no problem in any case...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like this which will work with both Farsi and Arabic numbers

```js
function toEnglishDigits(str) {
  const persianNumbers = ["۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"]
  const arabicNumbers = ["١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩", "٠"]
  const englishNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

  return str.split("").map(c => englishNumbers[persianNumbers.indexOf(c)] ||
    englishNumbers[arabicNumbers.indexOf(c)] || c).join("")
}

console.log(toEnglishDigits("۶٦۵any٥32"))
```

Comment: Your method also works and looks better newer and cleaner than thesecond method. But in your method, three of the Arabic numbers `٤ and ٥,٦‍` are not converted to English! Of course, as I replied to another comment. It works in a raw HTML. But it doesn't work on the WooCommerce payment page. The problem is so strange that what makes a code work, is that only three of the numbers in it are not converted and the same three numbers do not work! I started my work with the second method. However I still have a lot of confusion about why other methods don't work properly, and only this method works.

Comment: @PaulVek it looks like the problem is somewhere else, because it work for these characters for me

Comment: yes. now I found a problem. can you help me now? I use also this part of code in my function `// Remove non-numeric characters // var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` for this, conflict with numbers `٤,٥,٦‍` but I was before this condition I mean Remove non-numeric characters. run `var convertedValue = toEnglishDigits(currentPhoneValue);` And when the characters are converted to English before any other command and condition; There should be no more interference and no conversion. And if there is any interference or problem. Why are there only three numbers for this?

Comment: See, we only allowed numbers 0 to 9 with this `var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` and everything else should be removed. Then, so that this does not cause the numbers typed in Persian and Arabic languages to be rejected, we came and placed instructions to convert the numbers into English. but width these conditions. why not any problems with any numbers in English/Persian and Arabic converted correctly but just not converting `٤,٥,٦‍` nums? And does it interfere with the order I mentioned? And why there is no problem with the method two function?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all characters have a unique Unicode value between the different languages you could store them in a single object or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance with their decimal counterpart.

```js
const decimalMap = new Map([
  // Persian
  ["۰", "0"],
  ["۱", "1"],
  ["۲", "3"],
  // ...

  // Arabic
  ["٠", "0"],
  // ...
]);
```

With `decimalMap` defined translating the characters is as simple as checking if they're present within `decimalMap`. If a character is not present, keep it as is.

```js
function toEnglishDigits(string) {
  return Array.from(string, char => decimalMap.get(char) ?? char).join("");
}
```

The above uses [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to split the string into characters (and keep Unicode surrogate pairs intact). We then check the `decimalMap` for a translation with [`decimalMap.get(char)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) if the character is not in the `Map` instance `undefined` will be returned. Which in turn causes the [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) operator to return the right hand side of the operator (the original character).

```js
// build the decimal translation map
const decimalMap = new Map();

function addDecimals(decimals) {
  const chars = Array.from(decimals);
  chars.forEach((char, index) => decimalMap.set(char, index.toString()));
}

addDecimals("۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"); // Persian
addDecimals("٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"); // Arabic

// string translation
function toEnglishDigits(string) {
  return Array.from(string, char => decimalMap.get(char) ?? char).join("");
}

// snippet event handlers
document.forms["convert-digits"].addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.elements.output.value = toEnglishDigits(this.elements.input.value);
});

document.getElementById("input-characters").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName !== "BUTTON") return;
  document.forms["convert-digits"].elements.input.value += event.target.textContent;
});
```

```css
form {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#input-characters label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
}

#input-characters button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<form id="convert-digits">
  <input name="input" />
  <button>convert</button>
  <input name="output" disabled />
</form>

<div id="input-characters">
  <div>
    <label>Persian</label>
    <button>۰</button>
    <button>۱</button>
    <button>۲</button>
    <button>۳</button>
    <button>۴</button>
    <button>۵</button>
    <button>۶</button>
    <button>۷</button>
    <button>۸</button>
    <button>۹</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Arabic</label>
    <button>٠</button>
    <button>١</button>
    <button>٢</button>
    <button>٣</button>
    <button>٤</button>
    <button>٥</button>
    <button>٦</button>
    <button>٧</button>
    <button>٨</button>
    <button>٩</button>
  </div>
</div>
```