# How to convert numbers in JavaScript, and problems with commands to remove non-numeric characters on a keyboard with Tel input

Tags: javascript, jquery, customization

following this answer [What's the solution and the right way to convert digits in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851292/whats-the-solution-and-the-right-way-to-convert-digits-in-javascript)

For Now, I try to use this method to convert numbers in a phone number field with tel input type.

```JS
function toEnglishDigits(str) {
  const persianNumbers = ["۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"]
  const arabicNumbers = ["١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩", "٠"]
  const englishNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

  return str.split("").map(c => englishNumbers[persianNumbers.indexOf(c)] ||
    englishNumbers[arabicNumbers.indexOf(c)] || c).join("")
}
```

but I found a problem and need help with this.
I use also this part of the code in my function

```js
// Remove non-numeric characters
var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

I think conflicts with numbers ٤,٥,٦‍ because maybe these numbers its not normal Arabic, maybe eat Eastern Arabic! india and something like this.

however, before this condition (Remove non-numeric characters). I use the below first with a higher priority.

```js
var convertedValue = toEnglishDigits(currentPhoneValue);
```

When the characters are converted to English before any other command and condition like (removing non-numeric characters);
There should be no more interference and no conversion. And if there is any interference or problem. Why is it like this only for these three numbers and the rest of the numbers are not a problem?

See, we only allowed numbers 0 to 9 with this `var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` and everything else should be removed.

Then, in order not to reject the numbers typed in Farsi and Arabic, we came and put the instructions to convert the numbers into English. Before anything else needs to be done.

why not any problems with any numbers in English/Persian and Arabic in convert, but just not converting ٤,٥,٦‍ nums? What should I do and how to solve the problem?

I use other methods like

`var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^\d0-90-9]/g, '');`

or

`var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]/g, '');`

, or Even

`var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^\d0-90-94-6]/g, '');`

and this one!

`var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/\D/g, '');`

but it didn't make any difference, except that instead of hiding (removing); They would no longer disappear from the field. They stayed in the field, but without conversion, and again conversion did not work for them!

For the last thing
When I use this code to convert numbers. Those three numbers are accepted and converted and there is no problem for them. other than this; No other function works properly.

```javascript
var currentPhoneValue = phoneField.val();

// Convert Persian and Arabic digits to English using the shared utility function
var convertedValue = convert_number.toNormal(currentPhoneValue);

var convert_number = (function () {
    var numerals = {
        persian: ["۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹"],
        arabic: ["٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"]
    };

    return {
        toNormal: function (str) {
            if (!str) {
                return '';
            }
            var num, i, len = str.length, result = "";

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                num = numerals["persian"].indexOf(str[i]);
                num = num != -1 ? num : numerals["arabic"].indexOf(str[i]);
                if (num == -1) num = str[i];
                result += num;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}

var numericPhoneValue = convertedValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

why? Also, I don't want to use this function. Because I feel it is old and slow. And the function I am going to use that I wrote at the beginning of the question is better and faster. But those problems exist and I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to *convert* or *remove* or still something else. Please provide examples of input and expected output for them.

Comment: Original function is faster. It is well optimised and uses pure cycle instead of creating closures and call stack for each letter.
Anyway, I tried to convert  '٤,٥,٦‍' with your function and it worked fine.

Comment: It is completely clear and complete. There is an input field. Only numbers 0 to 9 are accepted. Non-numeric characters including letters and ... are removed. The problem is explained clearly and completely. The problem is in converting some Persian and Arabic numbers to English.

Comment: for answer @Zibx Please convert the function together with the function to remove numeric characters (test together) and remove non-numeric characters. Then he sees the problem. You probably just tested the first convert function. It works fine on its own. When we use it together with removing non-numeric characters. Then some Arabic numbers are not converted to English, so they are removed from the field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your issue, but I would start by properly handling Unicode strings.

There are a few issues with your current code, let's start of with:

```
string.split("")
```

Taken from the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#description) documentation:

> **Warning:** When the empty string (`""`) is used as a separator, the string is **not** split by *user-perceived characters* ([grapheme
> clusters](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)) or unicode characters (code points), but by UTF-16 code
> units. This destroys [surrogate pairs](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2). See ["How do you get a
> string to a character array in JavaScript?" on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-to-get-character-array-from-a-string/34717402#34717402).

Similarly using `string.length` will return the amount of UTF-16 code units. It does **not** return the amount of user-perceived characters. The same applies for `string[index]` will also access UTF-16 code unit. It does **not** access the user-perceived character at index `index`.

To properly handle Unicode characters you should convert the string into an array using the [string iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator). The iterator is used by [`Array.from(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `[...string]`, a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

Alternatively you can make a regex Unicode aware by adding the [`u`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode) (Unicode) flag.

---

With the above explained I suggest you start with the following actions:

1. Made sure you add the `u` flag to your regex, so it doesn't destroy surrogate pairs.
2. Use `Array.from(string)`, `[...string]`, `string.split(/(?:)/u)` (empty regex with `u` flag, `(?:)` is necessary because `//` is a comment) to split a string based on user-perceived character.
3. Do **not** use `string.length`, `string[index]`, split it into a character array first with one of the above options. Then iterate through the array, not through the string.

I don't know if these recommendations solve your problem, but it makes your code less error prone. Which might make the actual problem easier to debug.

Comment: can you write an example of the complete and modified code?

Comment: In the first given implementation of `toEnglishDigits` you would only have to replace `str.split("")` with `Array.from(str)`. Then also update the regex in `convertedValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')` to `/[^0-9]/gu` (notice the `u` flag).