# How to fix cursor typewriter Jump to end Issue during convert number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

following these questions {[What's the solution and the right way to convert digits in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851292/whats-the-solution-and-the-right-way-to-convert-digits-in-javascript)} and {[How to convert numbers in JavaScript, and problems with commands to remove non-numeric characters on a keyboard with Tel input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77866289/how-to-convert-numbers-in-javascript-and-problems-with-commands-to-remove-non-n)} I want to express one of the other problems.

there are not any differences in which method for converting numbers, however in all methods, I have a little problem with this.

my problem is the keyboard typewriter pointer jumps to the end if select a number in the middle of numbers with the mouse or touch (on mobile) and change One or more numbers. please see this image pasted in below for clarification Also add a JSFiddle link.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/paulvek/4js965fr/7/

```js
const phoneNumberInput = document.getElementById('phoneNumberInput');
phoneNumberInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  const phoneNumberValue = event.target.value;
  const englishPhoneNumberValue = toEnglishDigits(phoneNumberValue);
  const numericPhoneValue = englishPhoneNumberValue.replace(/[^\d۰-۹٠-٩]/g, ''); // Added line
  event.target.value = numericPhoneValue;
});

function toEnglishDigits(str) {
  const persianNumbers = ["۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"];
  const arabicNumbers = ["١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩", "٠"];
  const englishNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];

  return str.split("").map(c => englishNumbers[persianNumbers.indexOf(c)] ||
    englishNumbers[arabicNumbers.indexOf(c)] || c).join("")
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" id="phoneNumberInput" />
```

If the user selects one of the middle digits with the English keyboard and changes it, it will change there and the blinking type indicator of the same type pointer will stay there.

But if he selects and changes one of the middle digits with the Persian or Arabic keyboard, the change is done correctly. But the problem is that the text cursor jumps to the end.

This problem occurs only when typing or pasting Farsi and Arabic. What do you think is the problem? can you solve it?

Only when he wants to choose two or three numbers from among the numbers and change them. By writing the first number, it jumps to the end, and then the second digit, which should have been written next to the first digit in the same place he had chosen, goes to the end, and this messes up everything. If you test, you will see that there is no such problem with English.

Comment: `event.target.value = numericPhoneValue;` will move the cursor to the end of the field. You would need to remember the selection information and use ranges

Comment: As above: when you set .value it moves the caret (cursor/input-point) to the end.   For `<input>` you need to store/restore the `.selectionStart` possibly and `.selectionEnd` depending on how you want it to work.   `Range` is usually used for document selection (eg div text) - I'm not clear if it can be used for `<input>`

Comment: thank you. My problem was solved by your ways. Later I will write an answer and include the complete code I made. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by following on comments and suggested solutions.

Now here is working well code. Tested and works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Phone Number Input</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="tel" id="phoneNumberInput" />

<script>
const phoneNumberInput = document.getElementById('phoneNumberInput');
let cursorStart = 0; // Variable to store the start position of the selection
let cursorEnd = 0;   // Variable to store the end position of the selection

phoneNumberInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  const phoneNumberValue = event.target.value;

  // Get the current cursor position
  cursorStart = phoneNumberInput.selectionStart;
  cursorEnd = phoneNumberInput.selectionEnd;

  const englishPhoneNumberValue = toEnglishDigits(phoneNumberValue);
  const numericPhoneValue = englishPhoneNumberValue.replace(/[^\d۰-۹٠-٩]/g, '');

  // Update the value
  event.target.value = numericPhoneValue;

  // Set the cursor position back to the original position
  phoneNumberInput.setSelectionRange(cursorStart, cursorEnd);
});

function toEnglishDigits(str) {
  // Your toEnglishDigits function remains unchanged
  const persianNumbers = ["۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"];
  const arabicNumbers = ["١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩", "٠"];
  const englishNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];

  return str.split("").map(c => englishNumbers[persianNumbers.indexOf(c)] ||
    englishNumbers[arabicNumbers.indexOf(c)] || c).join("");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```